# Как использовать яндекс пиксель для сбора статистики подгрузки скрипта?

Tags: javascript, реклама

У меня есть код, который по сути представляет собой плеер с рекламой и видео. Код разместили на сайте и теперь надо получить статистику загрузки этого скрипта. Для этого создал Яндекс пиксель, но я не понимаю, как использовать его для своих целей. Понятно, что Яндекс создавал пиксель для использования его в своей экосистеме, со своими баннерами и т.д. Можно ли его вообще использовать для сбора статистики о загрузке скрипта?

Я пытался сделать так:

```
function widgetLoaded() {
        _request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        _request.open("GET", YANDEX_PIXEL_URL, false);
        _request.send();
    }
```

но статистика не собирается.

Возможно нужно разместить ссылку пикселя на странице, например, в теге `<img>` после загрузки определенной части скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, яндекс пиксель - это картинка, поэтому я просто завернул ссылку на пиксель в атрибут **src** тега `<img>` и разместил его на странице.